# What's causing "Unable to retrieve native address from ByteBuffer object"?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

As a very novice Java programmer, I probably should not mess with that kind of things. Unfortunately, I'm using a library which have a method that accepts a `ByteBuffer` object and throws when I try to use it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Unable to retrieve native address from ByteBuffer object
```

Is it because I'm using a non-direct buffer?

edit:
There's not a lot of my code there. The library I'm using is jNetPcap, and I'm trying to dump a packet to file. My code takes an existing packet, and extract a ByteBuffer out of it:

```
byte[] bytes = m_packet.getByteArray(0, m_packet.size());
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
```

Then it calls on of the dump methods of jNetPcap that takes a ByteBuffer.

Comment: It would help if you'd show the code you're using.

Comment: I don't think it would be of any help, but here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many JNI calls expect a direct ByteBuffer. Even the standard libraries in Oracle Java 6.0 expect this and if you provide them with a heap ByteBuffer they copy your data to/from a direct one for you.  In your case, you have a byte[] which can be copied to a direct ByteBuffer.  note: creating a direct ByteBuffer is expensive and you should cache/recycle them if you can.

```
// the true size is always a multiple of a page anyway.
static final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4096); 

// synchronize the buffer if you need to, or use a ThreadLocal buffer as a simple cache.
byte[] bytes = m_packet.getByteArray(0, m_packet.size());
buffer.clear();
buffer.put(bytes);
buffer.flip();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you've provided it appears you are using a ByteBuffer implementation that doesn't allow the Native code to get access to the underlying memory structure. It is attempting to access the direct memory in your ByteBuffer, which it probably shouldn't be doing, and is failing because the class deriving from ByteBuffer doesn't store data directly.

If this is critical code you can't change, your best bet would be to create a ByteBuffer using the Java implementation, then copy the original data into your temporary buffer; Pass the new buffer to your native method. I would then profile the code to see if it is a performance impact.

Here is an example of how to do this. I am a little hesitant to use `rewind()` and `limit()` as I don't know what the implementation of your ByteBuffer will return so check to make sure it implements the interface of ByteBuffer correctly.

This code illegally access index 3 on purpose to show that extra data isn't added.

`public static void main(String[] args) {`

```
    // This will be your implementation of ByteBuffer that
    // doesn't allow direct access.
    ByteBuffer originalBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{12, 50, 70});


    originalBuffer.rewind();
    byte[] newArray = new byte[originalBuffer.limit()];
    originalBuffer.get(newArray, 0, newArray.length);

    ByteBuffer newBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(newArray);

    System.out.println("Limit: " + newBuffer.limit());
    System.out.println("Index 0: " + newBuffer.get(0));
    System.out.println("Index 1: " + newBuffer.get(1));
    System.out.println("Index 2: " + newBuffer.get(2));
    System.out.println("Index 3: " + newBuffer.get(3));
}
```

*Output:*

Limit: 3

Index 0: 12

Index 1: 50

Index 2: 70

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:514)

    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:121)

    at stackoverflow_4534583.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap does not create a 'direct' byte buffer. A direct byte buffer typically results from using the memory mapping API. Whoever wrote the JNI code you are using wasn't kind to you insofar as they didn't write the code to tolerate a non-direct buffer.

However, all is not lost: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect(int)

will do what you need.